# Maya Python terrain generator

Tags: python, maya, terrain, heightmap

My terrain generator:

```
#imports
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random


#variables
landsub = 100 #number of subdivisions on the plane
landsize = 400 #size of the plane
maxheight = 100
land = cmds.polyPlane( sx=landsub, sy=landsub, w=landsize, h=landsize)
vtxCount = cmds.polyEvaluate(v=True)
print land
values = [random.triangular(0,1,0) for i in xrange(10)]

#code
for x in range(vtxCount):
    cmds.select(cl=True)
    cmds.select(land[0] + '.vtx[' + str(x) + ']')
    cmds.move(values[x] * maxheight, y=True, absolute=True)

cmds.select(land[0])
#cmds.polySmooth(dv = 1)
```

I'm trying to make `maxheight` and `vtxCount` variables interdependent; number of vertices on maximum height should be the smallest, rising until the most vertices are on the minimum height. With my code most vertices are in the mid-height and rarely any on the minimum height. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
#imports
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random
#variables
landsub = 100 #number of subdivisions on the plane
landsize = 400 #size of the plane
maxheight = 100
land = cmds.polyPlane( sx=landsub, sy=landsub, w=landsize, h=landsize)
vtxCount = range(cmds.polyEvaluate(v=True))
random.shuffle(vtxCount)
values = [random.triangular(0,1,0) for i in xrange(10)]
values_count = len(values)
SEED = 448
random.seed(SEED)
optimize_setter = []

#code
for x in vtxCount:
    mod = x % values_count
    # cmds.move(values[mod-1] * maxheight, land[0] + '.vtx[' + str(x) + ']',y=True, absolute=True)
    optimize_setter += [float(0),values[mod-1]*maxheight,float(0)]
cmds.setAttr('pPlane1.vtx[:]', *optimize_setter)
cmds.select(land[0])
```

If you want more values around 0, you could change values to have more .1 values. Im not sure what is your problem.

```
values = []
high_values = [random.triangular(0,1,0) for i in xrange(3)]
low_values = [random.uniform(0, .2), for i in xrange(7)]
values = low_values + high_values
```

## EDIT

```
#imports
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random
#variables
landsub = 100 #number of subdivisions on the plane
landsize = 400 #size of the plane
maxheight = 15
land = cmds.polyPlane( sx=landsub, sy=landsub, w=landsize, h=landsize)
vtxnb = cmds.polyEvaluate(v=True)
vtxCount = range(vtxnb)

values = []
high_values = [random.triangular(0,1,0) for i in xrange(vtxnb/10)]
low_values = [random.uniform(0, .3) for i in xrange(vtxnb/2)]
values = low_values + high_values
values_count = len(values)
SEED = 448
random.seed(SEED)
random.shuffle(vtxCount)
random.shuffle(values)
optimize_setter = []

#code
for x in vtxCount:
    mod = x % values_count
    # cmds.move(values[mod-1] * maxheight, land[0] + '.vtx[' + str(x) + ']',y=True, absolute=True)
    optimize_setter += [float(0),values[mod-1]*maxheight,float(0)]
cmds.setAttr('pPlane1.vtx[:]', *optimize_setter)
cmds.select(land[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Terrain generation is a fun problem, unfortunately it often requires a good deal of fiddling to get a satisfying result.

The 'maya' part of the problem is nicely handled in @drweeny's answer: you just need to bulk set the `.vtx` attributes of a polyPlane.  Here's a similar way to do it, the main difference is that this function takes an array of positions that works like a bitmap: it's a list whose contents are lists, representing rows and columns in a heightmap, ie :  `[ [0,1],  [2,3] ]` representing

```
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
```

as a grid.  Turning that into a polyplane is pretty easy:

```
def array_to_plane (array):
    # this expects that array is an list-of-lists
    # arranged as  [ [0,1,2], [3,4,5], ... etc  ]

    h = len(array)
    w = len(array[0])

    # this makes a plane with the same number of samples as your array
    plane, _  = cmds.polyPlane(width = 1, height = 1, sx = w -1 , sy=h-1)
    # the zeros are here just so the final argument list is a set of xyz
    # positions       
    setter = []
    for row in array:
        for column in row:
            setter.append (0.0)
            setter.append (column)
            setter.append (0.0)
    cmds.setAttr(plane + '.vtx[:]', *setter, type='double3')
    return plane
```

The interesting -- and tricky -- part is actually filling out that grid to make a terrain that doesn't look too much like random noise.  There are a lot of techniques but the basics are:

#### Randomization

You do want to apply random numbers to your height map.  Luckily python's [random module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility) has a lot of great options for noises with different distribution.  Here's a simple function that pokes random numbers into a map grid:

```
def randomize(map, scale):
    rows = len(map)
    columns = len(map[0]

    # loop over the map and add random values
    for r in  range(rows): 
        for c in range(columns):
            map[r][c] += (random.gauss(0,1) * scale)
```

#### Scales

A grid of random numbers does not look like terrain -- it's too chaotic. A very common technique is to apply the randomizations at different physical sizes to simulate a mix of large and small features.  The easiest way to to that is to start with a small map and then progressively upscale it -- that will give you a mix of features that vary in size.

Here's a cheap way to take a heightmap grid and just double its contents in each dimension. If you do that a few times and add some randomization on top, you get a mix of features from very large to very small.

```
def upsize(heightmap):
    output = []
    for row in heightmap:
        new_row = []
        for each_value in row:
            # first double the entries in the horizontal direction
            new_row.append(each_value)
            new_row.append(each_value)

        # then add two copies of the row to the output.
        # don't add it twice -- add a copy to keep
        # the data independent
        output.append(new_row)
        output.append(new_row[:])

    return output
```

Running that on a map like `[ [0,1], [2,3] ]`  would produce a map like 

      `[ [0,0,1,1], 
        [0,0,1,1], 
        [2,2,3,3], 
        [2,2,3,3]]`

#### Filtering

You don't want each sample in your heightmap to be independent of its neighbors: that's rare in nature and looks pretty bad.  In programs like photoshop you generate a blur effect using a ['kernel'](http://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/) which is basically just a weighted average of a pixel and its neighbors.  There are lots of options here (it's a good area to investigate for your project).  Here's a very simple blur kernel that takes a one our map grids and returns a new one that is blurred; you'll see that after adding up different pixel weights we also use a linear interpolation to control the strength of the blur:

```
def blur(map):
    output = []
    for row in map:
        output.append(row[:])

    width = len(map[0])
    height = len(map)

    for row in range (1, height-1):
        for column in range (1, height-1):
            v = 0
            v += map [row-1][column - 1]
            v += map [row-1][column] * 2
            v += map [row-1][column + 1]
            v += map [row][column - 1] * 2
            v += map [row][column] * 4
            v += map [row][column + 1] * 2
            v += map [row+1][column - 1]
            v += map [row+1][column]  * 2
            v += map [row+1][column + 1]
            v = v / 16.0

            # lerp the final output based on amount; 0 = no blur, 1 = full blur)
            output[row][column] =  v

    return output
```

There are a lot of options for this step which will affect how your final output looks. You can experiment really easily with filter kernels using [Photoshop's custom filter](http://www.naturefocused.com/articles/photography-image-processing-kernel.html) which is really just a simple kernel editor.

### Putting it together

With randomization, scaling and filtering you have enough to make an interesting terrain generation toolkit.  The common thread is that you're doing all the hard work on 'bitmap' of 'pixels' arranged as a list - of -lists and when you're done you turn it over to maya to make a final object.

Here is a very basic way to put these together.  I'd encourage you to take this apart and put it back together in ways that satisfy your creative ideas. Writing the pieces as separate functions that work on the heightmap lists makes it easy to add or tweak behaviors without breaking the whole thing.

```
def fractalize(iterations, scale=1.0,  seed = None):

    # this lets you make it repeatable if you want
    if seed:
        random.seed(seed)

    # make a 2-2 starter map
    map = [ [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0] ] 

    randomize(map, scale)

    for n in range(1, iterations):
        map = upsize(map)
        map = blur(map)

        # this turns down the randomization
        # in each successive step... you could
        # use many formulas here for different effects
        randomize(map, scale / 2**n)

    return array_to_plane(map)

fractalize(7, 0.125, seed=1234)
```

Be *careful* with that iterations number: each iteration *quadruples* the number of vertices, so setting it too high will sink you maya.  A value of 8 produces a plane with 255 x 255 vertices; use with care.

Some things to try for making this your own:
 *  when -- and how often -- do you want to add blurs ?
 *  what happens if you use a different blur kernel ?
 *  what happens if you change `randomize(map, scale / 2**n)` to some other formula?
 *  what could you do to the bitmap to simulate water levels?